# How livewire wire:ignore can ignore a specific wire:model input in PHP?

Tags: laravel-livewire

After doing a search using an input field with "wire:model", the page shows some results. This part OK.
There is a listener, and when you scroll to the end of the page, when you reach the bottom, automatically emits (javascript windows.livewire.emit) an event that loads more results without refreshing the page.
This is OK too.

Issue:
When I start typing again in the Search field/input the results disappear, the page is empty...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpgUK.png)

If I use "wire:ignore" the page keeps the results, but can't load more results, despite calling the function to load.

Ah, I've tried wire:ignore.self already, but it didn't work, just cleaned the results of the page too...

Is there a way to not clear the page while typing (using a wire:model input), using a "windows.livewire.emit", rendering the page and loading more results?

Any idea will save my week, job, brain....  :)

Here some parts pf code:

```
<input wire:model.debounce.1ms="search" @click="open = ! open" @click.outside="open = false" type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-describedby="search" @keyup="select(event)" autofocus autocomplete="off">

<div> {{-- HERE where I've tried put wire:ignore --}}
@if (isset(self::$lists))
    @empty(!self::$lists)
        @if (count(self::$lists)>0)
            <div>
                <div class="px-2">
                    <div class="grid w-full grid-cols-2">
                        <ul role="list" wire:loading.delay.class='opacity-50' class="grid grid-cols-2 col-span-2 gap-y-2 gap-x-2 lg:gap-y-4 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-5 xl:gap-y-4 xl:grid xl:grid-cols-8">
                            @foreach (self::$lists as $key => $list)
                                <li wire:key="{{ $list?->test_id ?? $list['test_id'] }}" id="{{ $list?->test_id ?? $list['test_id'] }}" class="max-w-[193px] min-h-[250px] max-h-[250px]">
                                    <div class="containerText hover:opacity-70">
                                        <p class="text-gray-400">{{ $list?->test_desc ?? $list['test_desc'] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
    @endempty
@endif
</div>
```

Comment: Debounce should be 250ms or more. Can you show the rest of the code and views?